# Java parse oracle timestamp to date.util.date

Tags: java, oracle, date, timestamp

i want to parse oracle timestamp (`01-MAY-12 01.00.47.000000000 PM`) to `java.util.Date`
i used this:

```
Date dateStart=new SimpleDateFormat("yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S").parse("01-MAY-12 01.00.47.000000000 PM");
```

but i get this error

> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2012-5-1.13.0. 47. 0"

Answer (score 6):

You shouldn't have to parse anything. Use one of the [ResultSet.getTimestamp()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getTimestamp%28int%29) methods, and you'll have a [`java.sql.Timestamp`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) object directly, which extends `java.util.Date`.

```
java.sql.Timestamp ts = myResultSet.getTimestamp( … );
```

And this will have the additional advantage of being portale across databases and locales.

Comment: Or, if using JDBC 4.2 or later, and Java 8 or later, you may be able to retrieve an `java.time.Instant` via the `ResultSet::getObject` method.

Answer (score 1):

"yy-MM-dd"?

"01-MAY-12"

Is your day number really "12" and your year "01"?

And how come your error shows "2012-5-1.13.0. 47. 0", which is presumably a date in yet another format?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to access it using JDBC then as @JB Nizet  suggested use `getTimestamp()` or if you just have String and need to parse to Date then do it by following

Try with following format

```
01-MAY-12 01.00.47.000000000 PM

yy-MMM-dd hh.mm.ss.SSSSSSSSSS a
```

- [Working demo](http://ideone.com/1Bwq0)

Comment: It doesn't work properly for time stamps which have non zero nano seconds i.e `01-MAY-12 01.00.47.999999999` PM